# Can not reset TD style

Tags: css

I have removed padding from all TD elements in stylesheet. But I have a special table having `cellpadding="10"`. Its TD are rendered having 0px padding due to above mentioned style.

how should I reset TD padding to nothing so it inherits the 10px padding from cellpadding?

```css
td {padding:0}

#specialtable td { 
  /* What should I write here? */ 
}
```

```html
<table id="specialtable" cellpadding="10" style="border:1px solid #555555">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Typo: in your CSS you have `#specialtable` (lowercase `t`), but in your HTML the id you have `specialTable` (uppercase `T`).

Comment: @noisypixy that's just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [:not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to define the padding for all `td` *except* those under a `#specialTable`.

```css
table:not(#specialTable) td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="specialTable" cellpadding="10" style="border:1px solid #555555">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you this works fine in my case. But in general do you have any idea how to reset the previous style to nothing?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour usually you could use the [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) keyword (e.g. `padding: initial`) or similars, but they didn't work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) one can see that we can define an `inherit` value for the `padding`, which should `inherit` the `padding` from the parent. As far as I know that is the default value. So you can set the padding to default by giving it the `inherit` value.

Comment: Unfortunately inherit is not working for `cellpadding` as the `cellpadding` is not a css style but a HTML tag.